# Authentication check for non auth url in laravel passport api

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i am using passport authentication for my Laravel 5.4 API.here i have a api for company details and it is a non auth api.i need to check logined user liked this company using auth in this url ...how i can do this.

This is my route

```
   Route::get('/company/{company}','Api\V1\CompanyController@show');
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api','prefix'=>'v1'], function(){
//auth urls
}
```

and this is my controller

```
class CompanyController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Company $company,Request $request)
    {
        $data                           =   array();
        $flag                           =   0;
        $data['status']                 =   1;
        $data['message']                =   'success';
        $data['baseUrl']                =    url('/');
        $data['is_login']               =   Auth::check();
```

Here is_login always return false,if i added autherization token in headers of api.

Comment: so you have a section that doesn't require authentication but you still want to get an authenticated user?

Comment: routes with `auth:api` give an error if the guest? `auth()->check()` works elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your default guard set as?

`Auth::check()` is `Auth::guard(null)->check()` which uses the current default guard.

If you want to check for an api you probably want to use the `api` guard just like your `auth` middleware is using when you use `auth:api`.

`Auth::guard('api')->check()` tells it to explicitly use the `api` guard instead of what the default is, which could be anything since we don't know what you have set.

When the `auth` middleware is ran it actually will set the default guard for you depending upon what guards are passed to it and which one it can resolve a user from. Which is why you can just call `Auth::user()` and get the correct user from the correct guard, because the middleware sets the current to the one that resolved the user. (When calling routes that have this middleware)